# Connect 2 SHT25 to measure 2 sets of temperature and humidity at 2 different sites

Tags: sensor

I want to connect 2 SHT25 to measure 2 sets of temperature and humidity at 2 different sites . How should I connect it to Raspberry Pi 3. Thanks for your help

Comment: your can try tca9548a i2x mux module：（　https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32827197104.html　）

Comment: thanks I ordered 2, they were available in India https://thinkrobotics.in at a low price, I will use and update.

Comment: You are welcome.  From time to time I read about ThinkRobotics and visit them to catch up new products. They are impressive.  Have a nice project.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The SHT25 has an I2C interface. Use this I2C interface to connect the sensors to the Raspberry Pi. There are many online examples, and sample code; here's two that look reasonable:

- [Configuring I2C](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-4-gpio-setup)
- [Raspberry Pi I2C - Python](https://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-I2C-Python/)

#### EDIT - 20190703:

As Dmitry has pointed out in the comment, you will need to overcome a limitation that's "*built in*" to the **SHT25** chip: It has one, and only one, I2C address available. And since you indicated you wish to interface two (2) of these sensors to your RPi, this poses an additional hurdle. As I see it, you have two options to clear this hurdle:

1. **Use an I2C multiplexer device (as suggested by ttfong01 in the comments):** There are a variety of resources available online to help with this if you wish to consult them ([here's one example](https://www.brainy-bits.com/i2c-multiplexer-tca9548a/))
2. **Use a temp/humid sensor that provides at least two I2C addresses:** In my opinion, this is the *cleaner*, simpler solution. One such sensor is the [DHT31](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/682/Sensirion_Humidity_Sensors_SHT3x_Datasheet_digital-1368032.pdf); it offers two user-selectable I2C addresses. The address is selected simply by tying the ADDR pin to logic high or low. If you need more than 2 addresses, this is also possible (refer to the data sheet for details).

Comment: I think the question is about connecting 2 devices with the same address to a single bus.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: Ach! You're right... it wasn't mentioned in the OP, but the SHT25 has only a single address available. Seems a silly decision by the IC mfr, but that's only my opinion. One **EDIT** coming up!